# Execution time required for executing a function/ method in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to check how much time a routine/ function takes for it's execution while debugging the code in Visual Studio 2008/ 2010?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 debug options for execution time monitoring?

Comment: Is there any way to check how much time a method is taking for it's execution? I'm using Visual studio 2008 and code is in C++.